# Does increasing number of iterations also increase chances of getting erroneous output in Kalman filter?

Tags: algorithm, kalman-filter

I found this very simple code online of Kalman filter

```
double frand() {
    return 2*((rand()/(double)RAND_MAX) - 0.5);
}

int main() {

    //initial values for the kalman filter
    float x_est_last = 0;
    float P_last = 0;
    //the noise in the system
    float Q = 0.022;
    float R = 0.617;

    float K;
    float P;
    float P_temp;
    float x_temp_est;
    float x_est;
    float z_measured; //the 'noisy' value we measured
    float z_real = 0.5; //the ideal value we wish to measure

    srand(0);

    //initialize with a measurement
    x_est_last = z_real + frand()*0.09;

    float sum_error_kalman = 0;
    float sum_error_measure = 0;

    for (int i=0;i<30;i++) {
        //do a prediction
        x_temp_est = x_est_last;
        P_temp = P_last + Q;
        //calculate the Kalman gain
        K = P_temp * (1.0/(P_temp + R));
        //measure
        z_measured = z_real + frand()*0.09; //the real measurement plus noise
        //correct
        x_est = x_temp_est + K * (z_measured - x_temp_est); 
        P = (1- K) * P_temp;
        //we have our new system

        printf("Ideal    position: %6.3f \n",z_real);
        printf("Mesaured position: %6.3f [diff:%.3f]\n",z_measured,fabs(z_real-z_measured));
        printf("Kalman   position: %6.3f [diff:%.3f]\n",x_est,fabs(z_real - x_est));

        sum_error_kalman += fabs(z_real - x_est);
        sum_error_measure += fabs(z_real-z_measured);

        //update our last's
        P_last = P;
        x_est_last = x_est;
    }

    printf("Total error if using raw measured:  %f\n",sum_error_measure);
    printf("Total error if using kalman filter: %f\n",sum_error_kalman);
    printf("Reduction in error: %d%% \n",100-(int)((sum_error_kalman/sum_error_measure)*100));


    return 0;
}
```

It is a pretty straightforward code for a newbie like me to understand.
Now, I changed the step size of loop counter from 1 to 3 and the error that I got was 0.4 reduced from 1.7. My question is : does increasing the number of iterations of Kalman filter make it to converge and then later diverge? or is it code-specific or some other attribute specific.

Comment: I don't think it is [tag:c] related question, but about the filter itself.

Answer (score 0):

Previously, I employed SSE which resulted in more error as the iterations were increased. However, now, I just subtracted the final resulting value from the original and it shows correct output.